# "Select all" shortcut ( Ctrl+A) doesn't work in Kubuntu (20.04)

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, shortcut-keys

[image]

The standard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is enabled in Standard Shortcuts under Settings  but it doesn't work in Dolphin, Kate, LOWriter, Firefox or anywhere else.
I cannot find a duplicate anywhere in the settings.

Removing or renaming `~/.config/kdeglobals` removes my settings without fixing this problem.

All other shortcuts seem to work fine.

The menu option "Select all" (to which  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is set and displayed in the menu) does work, but not the shortcut.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

---

- Adding another shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>) or as an alternative (second combination) works.

Although confusing, it looks like a hidden conflict somewhere, given that when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> works, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> - as alternative - does not.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, but noticed that my desktop seems to be configured by default with Emacs keybindings: Ctrl+A goes to one line begin, Ctrl+K yanks (cuts) the text, but Ctrl+Y pastes what is contained in another buffer, i.e. the one that gets filled with what one copies but selecting text and then Ctrl+C. Strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After facing the same problem on a different system with the Plasma desktop in which I had imported my saved shortcuts (and after seeing that the problem was absent in a live usb boot) it became clear that the problem was with my shortcuts.

The solution was to reset shortcuts: *Settings > Shortcuts > Global... > Defaults > All components*.

(Or just *Settings > Shortcuts > Shortcuts > Defaults* on more recent versions of Plasma.)